# Does an lvalue argument prefer an lvalue reference parameter over a universal reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, overload-resolution, universal-reference, forwarding-reference

While playing with universal references, I came across this instance where clang and gcc disagree on overload resolution.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {};

template<typename T>
void bar(T&) { std::cout << "void bar(T&)\n"; }

template<typename T>
void bar(T&&) { std::cout << "void bar(T&&)\n"; }

int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar(f);  // ambiguous on gcc, ok on clang
}
```

[gcc reports](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3455c14b41c46596320c5133c4621e7c-793367a52c22d67c60e8f4d72a2f51e2) the call above is ambiguous. However, [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3455c14b41c46596320c5133c4621e7c-6e9f1f680880347f6708b805c806db62) selects the `T&` overload and compiles successfully.

Which compiler is wrong, and why?

Edit: 
Tested the same code on VS2013 Preview, and it agrees with clang; except Intellisense, which is on gcc's side :-)

Comment: This is [GCC bug 54425](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54425).

Comment: Both intel(13.0.1) and pgi(13.4) compilers also yield an error about that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "universal reference" deduces the parameter to `foo&`. The first template also deduces the parameter to `foo&`.

C++ has a partial ordering rule for function templates that makes `T&` be more specialized than `T&&`.  Hence the first template must be chosen in your example code.

Comment: Found the standard reference - from N3691 section §14.8.2.4/9