# Templated function only taking rvalues

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

It's easy enough to write a function taking only lvalues

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&);
```

but because of [universal references](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers), writing one that only takes rvalue references isn't straight forward.  Is there a way to write a generic function that only takes rvalue refs? (the return type isn't really a concern)

```
template <typename T>
void only_rvals(T&&);
```

where

```
int i{};
only_rvals(i); // fails to compile
only_rvals(6); // successfully compiles
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a

```
template<class T>
void only_rvals(T&)=delete;
```

overload to the universal one.  It will be preferred, and generate an error if selected.

Alternatively, SFINAE check, or a post-C++1y requires clause, or a `static_assert`, or a tag dispatch using `is_reference` or similar would all work.

Ideally you want failure at point of call, clarity of code, clarity of diagnostic, robustness of solution, and extendable.  The post-C++1y requires will eventually be best.  `static_assert` gives a clear diagnostic (as can tag disptching, but you want a trait called `is_rvalue` dispatched to `true_type`), and SFINAE and `=delete` make the error occur at the call site.  `=delete` does not scale to more arguments, SFINAE is fragile.

SFINAE and `requires` allows alternative overloads to be used.  This may or may not be desired.

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's a [gcc bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979265/does-an-lvalue-argument-prefer-an-lvalue-reference-parameter-over-a-universal-re). Fixed in 4.9

Answer (score 4):

There are two possible solutions that I can see.  The first uses a `static_assert` to check at compile time whether or not the deduced type is an lvalue reference.  If it is, compilation fails on that line with whatever meaningful error you'd like to add

```
template <typename T>
void only_rvals(T&& t) {
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value,
            "I only work with rvalues");
    // ...
}
```

If you'd like this to fail "naturally" through the compiler with a (imo) hard to understand error, you can do so with a helper function (here using a `_impl`).  The called function uses `remove_reference` to call the helper function with a non-reference type for its template parameter.  This ensures the instantiated helper has an rvalue reference for its parameter type.  If the original type was an lvalue reference, the call will fail as the argument is attempted to be forwarded as an lvalue reference.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
void only_rvals_impl(T&& t) {
    //...
}

template <typename T>
void only_rvals(T&& t) {
    // no type deduction on this call, explicit instantiation
    only_rvals_impl<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(
            std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

A third solution from @dyp's comment using SFINAE

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{}, void>::type
only_rvals(T&& t)  {
    //...
}
```

the `void` in the `enable_if` is unnecessary as it's the default, but shown here for an easy-to-modify solution

Comment: Third solution: SFINAE. `template<class T> typename std::enable_if< !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{} >::type only_rvals(T&& t)`

Answer (score 0):

> 4. If P is an rvalue reference to a **cv-unqualified**

Take note of this requirement and sample code in standard.
All you need is "fake" const/volatile T&&

```
template <typename T>
void only_rvals(volatile T&&);
```

Comment: Finally a use for `volatile`.