# How to write a template function accepting && and const& both?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, move-semantics

For example

```
template<typename T> void f(T&& t) {}
template<typename T> void f(T const& t) {}
```

When I call

```
int i;
f(i); // call f(T&&) which I expect to call f(T const&), how to solve it?
f(10); // call f(T&&), that is fine
```

Comment: Is that you wish to overload a function to discriminate between r-values and l-values and the type is also templated?

Comment: Do you want rvalues to go to the `T&&` overload and lvalues to go to the `T const &` overload?

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25938749/3549027

Comment: In case you didn't know why this is a problem, it's because that first overload takes a _universal reference_ (which can bind to just about anything), not necessarily an rvalue reference as it would first appear. It's because `T&&` means something different in a "deduced" context. Welcome to C++. :/

Comment: Doing what you want to do is almost always wrong. Are you aware of Perfect Forwarding? With perfect forwarding, you only need the `T&&` version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That'd be one way:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if< !std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value >::type
f(T&& t) {}

template<typename T> void f(T const& t) {}
```

Another possibility is tag dispatching:

```
template<typename T>
void f_(const T&, std::true_type) { std::cout << "const T&\n"; }
template<typename T>
void f_(T&&, std::false_type) { std::cout << "T&&\n"; }

template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    f_(std::forward<T>(t), std::is_lvalue_reference<T>{} );
}
```

Comment: @P0W That's what I thought, too, but [nope](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3c3048525a93b69).

Comment: Ahh now I realized after seeing the possible implementation of `std::is_rvalue_reference`

Comment: `std::is_rvalue_reference< decltype(std::forward<T>(std::declval<T>()))` would work, though :) Or with `add_rvalue_reference<T>`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Talking about not seeing the forest because of the trees!

Answer (score 4):

An other alternative is:

```
template<typename T>
struct f_caller
{
    void operator () (T&& ) { std::cout << "T&&" << std::endl; }
    void operator () (T const& ) { std::cout << "const T&" << std::endl; }
};


template <typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
    f_caller<typename std::decay<T>::type>()(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/jQM0vr)