# Control to what kind of references `T` binds

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue-reference, forwarding-reference

While thinking about what can be done to solve the `std::min` [dangling reference problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721839/if-stdmax-returns-by-reference-as-it-must-might-that-lead-to-a-dangling-r), one thought I had was to add an overload (actually 3 - for each combination) for rvalues that would be deleted. The issue is that `T&&` would be a forwarding reference, not an rvalue reference.

I want to separate this question from `std::min` specifically and make it more general. The `std::min` can be taken as an example why would you need such a thing.

Lets simplify and generalize the problem:

```
// this has the same problem as `std::min`: if t binds to a temporary,
// and the result is assigned to `auto&`, the result is a dangled reference
template <class T>
const T& foo(const T& t)
{
  return t;
}

// incorrect attempt to prevent foo from being called with a temporary argument
// `T&&` is a forwarding reference, not an rvalue reference
template <class T>
const T& foo(T&& t) = delete;
```

The question is: How can you control to what kind of references a generic template parameter `T` could bind? And how could it scale for multiple arguments (like in `std::min` case)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your code, the following fails to compile

```
int i = 0;
foo(i);      // deleted function
```

The reason the forwarding reference overload is selected is because matching the other one requires `const` qualification. But if you were to write

```
int const i = 0;
foo(i);      // perfectly fine
```

In this case the overload taking the [lvalue reference is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17979265/241631).

Thus, in order to reject all rvalues, the `delete`d function needs to take a `T const&&` (this is what [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) does to reject rvalues)

```
template <class T>
const T& foo(const T& t)
{
  return t;
}

template <class T>
const T& foo(T const&& t) = delete;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e29db8632ffa965)

Comment: do you see an easier way to make this work for multiple parameters other than declaring every possible combination http://ideone.com/AJgqV8?

Comment: @bolov No, I don't see another way around. Looks like it's either a horrible looking `enable_if` expression or multiple deleted overloads. Neither is particularly appealing.

Comment: @bolov: By changing the correct method, you may do something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d59e75855413a7ac).

Answer (score 5):

You may do

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value>
foo(T&&) = delete;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9740cb8298d7b4a)

For 2 arguments, it becomes:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::enable_if_t<
    (std::is_rvalue_reference<T1&&>::value
    || std::is_rvalue_reference<T1&&>::value)
    && std::is_same<std::decay_t<T1>, std::decay_t<T2>>::value
>
foo(T1&&, T2&&) = delete;
```

Praetorian's version would be:

```
template <class T> void foo(const T&&, const T&) = delete;
template <class T> void foo(const T&, const T&&) = delete;
template <class T> void foo(const T&&, const T&&) = delete;
```

Comment: so simple and yet I missed it. It got way to complicated in my head.

Comment: @bolov: You have to do `foo(T1&&,T2&&)`. else they have both to be deduced as same type.